# Determining elements of a Boolean algebra by a set of ultrafilters

Tags: boolean-algebra, filters

Let $A$ be a Boolean algebra and let $Ult(A)$ be its Stone space. Let us say that a set $U\subseteq Ult(A)$ *determines* an element $a\in A$ if there exists $V\subseteq U$ such that
$$\big\{b\in A\!: (\forall u\in V)(b\in u)\ \wedge\ (\forall u\in U\setminus V)(b\notin u)\big\}=\{a\}.$$
Let us further say that $U\subseteq Ult(A)$ is *determining* if it determines all elements of $A$.

**Question:** Is there any characterization of determining sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a\in A$ denote $S(a)=\{u\in Ult(A)\!:a\in u\}$.
Then $\{S(a)\!:a\in A\}$ is a basis of the Stone topology on $Ult(A)$.

**Claim:** *A set $U\subseteq Ult(A)$ is determining if and only if it is dense in the Stone topology.*

*Proof.* Let $U\subseteq Ult(A)$ be determining, $a\in A$, $a\neq 0$. Then there is $V\subseteq U$ such that $\det(V,U)=\{a\}$, where
$$\det(V,U)=\big\{b\in A\!:(\forall u\in V)(b\in u)\ \wedge\ (\forall u\in U\setminus V)(b\notin u)\big\}.$$
Since $0\in\det(\emptyset,U)$, $V$ is nonempty.
For $u\in V$ we have $u\in S(a)\cap U$.
This proves one direction.

To prove the opposite, let $U$ be dense and $a\in A$. We have to find $V\subseteq U$ such that $\det(V,U)=\{a\}$.
Let $V=\{u\in U\!:a\in U\}$. Clearly, $a\in\det(V,U)$.
If $b\neq a$ then either $a\wedge b'\neq 0$ or $a'\wedge b\neq 0$.
Hence there exists $u\in U$ containing exactly one of elements $a,b$, thus $b\notin\det(V,U)$.
It follows that $\det(V,U)=\{a\}$.
*q.e.d.*